# Use gallery instead of ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, gallery, viewswitcher

I currently use a ViewSwitcher in my app but now I'm facing a problem because I need more than 2 views to switch between. 
As ViewSwitcher does not accept more than 2 children, I've read that it's possible to use the Gallery widget to do so.

Each view in the ViewSwitcher is different (one is a LinearLayout with a ListView and a Button inside and the other one is a LinearLayout with an ImageView and a TextView inside).

Will I be able to use the Gallery widget given my requirements?

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Some tutorial/example or so..?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ViewFlipper` which allows you more than 2 views and it's almost identical to `ViewSwitcher` (since both have the same super class). I don't recommend using `GalleryView` in this case since all your views will be different, thus your Gallery's adapter will look like a pile of crap.

Comment: Great! That did the trick! I don't know what I was thinking.. I was already using a ViewFlipper (SafeViewFlipper for that matter..) in another control of my app..